# Are there any traditions that believe in contemporary miracles but reject contemporary miraculous gifts?

Tags: terminology, denomination-survey, miracles, spiritual-gifts, cessationism

I'm intrigued by whether Christians holding such beliefs exist and how they rationalize their stance. Is it coherent to affirm that God still performs miracles while denying the ongoing bestowal of miraculous gifts?

More specifically, I'm curious about:

- Their understanding of what constitutes a miracle (as opposed to a mundane or natural event).
- Their distinction between miraculous and non-miraculous gifts.
- Their reasoning behind believing in the continuation of miracles.
- Their reasoning behind believing in the cessation of miraculous gifts.
- Whether they justify their position using exegesis only, an analysis of historical/empirical data, or a mixture of both.

Comment: I think all cessationists affirm God's working miracles, this is why they pray and hope for healing, but they somehow reject man's instrumentality in miracles, that's the point of their unbelief.

Comment: The last times are characterised by an increase in miracles, see Matthew 7:21-23, 24:24, Mark 13:22, 2 Thess 2:8-12, Rev 13:13,14, 16:14,19:20. All of these texts underline that these are miracles of Satan, not of God, nor of Christ nor of the Holy Spirit. This is accompanied by false doctrine.

Comment: @NigelJ Is this view advocated by a specific denomination, or are you just sharing your own personal and individual opinion on the matter?